# stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString giving strange error

Tags: ios, swift

For some reason, this is giving me an error.
`swearWordPair` is defined as a `[String]`. For example
`["Hello", "Hi"]`

`let swearWordsAndReplacements : [[String]] = [["anus", "butt"], ["arse", "butt"]]`

The error this gives me is

```
Cannot invoke 'stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString' with an argument list of type '(String, withString: String, options: NSStringCompareOptions, range: NSRange)
```

However, I looked up the parameters for this function and it seems all my parameters are right. Is this a swift bug?

```
var string = insult
for swearWordPair in swearWordsAndReplacements {
    string = string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(swearWordPair[0],
        withString: swearWordPair[1],
        options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch,
        range: NSMakeRange(0, count(string)))
}
```

Comment: This looks wrong. swearWordPair might be [String] but not [[String]]. Show the exact declarations.

Comment: fixed this issue in my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Range` is not an `NSRange`, but a `Swift` range.  In this case, you can pass `nil` to represent the entire `String`:

```
string = string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(swearWordPair[0],
    withString: swearWordPair[1],
    options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch,
    range: nil)
```

If you wanted to limit the range, you can create a `Range<String.Index>` like this:

```
var string = "I laid my head at the head of the bed"

// Only replace within the first 15 characters
let myrange = string.startIndex ..< advance(string.startIndex, 15)

string = string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("head",
    withString: "blanket",
    options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch,
    range: myrange)

println(string)
```

Output:

> I laid my blanket at the head of the bed